# Python InDesign scripting: How to run a preflight check?

Tags: python, adobe-indesign

[This guide](https://github.com/lohriialo/indesign-scripting-python) provides a very good overview of InDesign scripting using Python. I am able to open my document and export it to a PDF, but in addition to that I want to check if any textboxes have some overflowing text. I wanted to accomplish this using some preflight checking, but when I tried to call

> myPreflight = app.PreflightProcesses.add(myDocument, myProfile)

I got the error "Missing required parameter 'TargetObject' for method 'Add'.", although according to the [documentation](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#PreflightProcesses.html) I did provide the target object.

I would really appreciate a concrete example on how to check for overflowing text, as I am rather new to this approach. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Python snippet that works for me:

```
import win32com.client

app = win32com.client.Dispatch('InDesign.Application.CS6')
doc = app.Open(r'd:\temp\test.indd')

profile = app.PreflightProfiles.Item('Stackoverflow Profile')
print('Profile name:', profile.name)

process = app.PreflightProcesses.Add(doc, profile)
process.WaitForProcess()
results = process.processResults
print('Results:', results)

doc.Close()

input('\nDone... Press <ENTER> to close the window')
```

For my test file, when it has the 'Overset Text' error, it shows the output as follows:

[image]

If there is no error I'm getting this:

[image]

Of course you need to change the file name and profile name in the code with your actual file name and profile. And perhaps you need to change `CS6` with `CC.2020` or whatever you have.

Just in case, ExtendScript variant of the code (for the already opened document) looks like this:

```js
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var myProfile = app.preflightProfiles.item('Stackoverflow Profile');
var myPreflight = app.preflightProcesses.add(myDocument, myProfile);
myPreflight.waitForProcess();
var results = (myPreflight.processResults);
alert(results);
```